# Explain this higher-order function behavior

Tags: python, decorator

Can someone explain why version 1 and 2 execute at the same speed? I expected versions 2, 3, and 4 to take about the same amount of time.

```
def fib(n):
    return n if n in [0, 1] else fib(n-2)+fib(n-1)

def memoize(fn):
    stored_results = {}

    def memoized(*args):
        try:
            return stored_results[args]
        except KeyError:
            #nothing cached
            result = stored_results[args] = fn(*args)
            return result

    return memoized

#version 1 (unmemoized)
print timeit.timeit('fib(35)', 'from __main__ import fib', number=1)
print fib, '\n'

#version 2
memo_fib = memoize(fib)
print timeit.timeit('memo_fib(35)', 'from __main__ import memo_fib', number=1)
print memo_fib, '\n'

#version 3 (wrapped)
fib = memoize(fib)
print timeit.timeit('fib(35)', 'from __main__ import fib', number=1)
print fib, '\n'

#version 4 (w/ decoration line)
@memoize
def fib(n):
    return n if n in [0, 1] else fib(n-2)+fib(n-1)

print timeit.timeit('fib(35)', 'from __main__ import fib', number=1)
```

Results:

```
version 1:  4.95815300941
<function fib at 0x102c2b320> 

version 2:  4.94982290268
<function memoized at 0x102c2b410> 

version 3:  0.000107049942017
<function memoized at 0x102c2b488> 

version 4:  0.000118970870972
```

Comment: Use the `timeit` module for timing your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `memoize` function isn't actually replacing `fib` with `memo_fib`, it's just returning a new function.

That new function still recursively calls the original, un-memoized `fib`.

So, basically, you're only memoizing the very top level.

---

Within `fib`, the recursive call to `fib` is just using the module-global name. (Functions are basically no different from any other kind of value, and function names no different from any other kind of name, so if you define a function at the module global level, that's what it does. If you, e.g., disassemble the bytecode with `dis.dis(fib)`, you will see a `LOAD_GLOBAL` on the name `fib`.)

So, the easy fix is:

```
fib = memoize(fib)
```

Or just use `memoize` as a decorator, to make this harder to get wrong.

In other words, your examples 3 and 4.

Or, even more simply, use the built-in [`lru_cache`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) decorator. (Notice the second example in its documentation.)

---

If you want to be *really* sneaky: Define `fib` within a function body. It will end up referencing `fib` as a closure cell from the defining scope, rather than a global (`LOAD_DEREF` instead of `LOAD_GLOBAL` in disassembly). You can then reach into that scope and replace *its* `fib`, which means that your recursive function is now memoized "secretly" (the actual global `fib` isn't memoized, but the function it recursively calls is) and "safely" (nobody else has a reference to the closure cell except through `fib` itself).

Answer (score 1):

In version 2, you've stored the memoized version with a different name, so you wind up calling fib just as many times as in the first version. Your call stack looks like this:

```
memo_fib(35)
    fib(35)
        fib(34)
            fib(33)
        fib(33)
```

etc.

So you aren't actually receiving any benefit from the memoization in this case.